# Update an array with data from inputs

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, input

I have several inputs, which I am copying **n** times and I am trying to **add** numeric values from inputs in the array. I marked word "add" because an array may be already filled by other numbers.

I'm trying to apply method from **UncleDave's** answer here:
[JavaScript - Add Value from input box to array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47078498/javascript-add-value-from-input-box-to-array/47078563)

**Example:**

I have an array:

```
var exampleArray = [[1, 1.5], [1, 1], [0, 25.5]];
```

**What I have done:**

Wrote value 25 in first input. Wrote value 1.5 in the second input.

Create two new inputs.

Wrote value 25.4 in first input. Wrote value 1 in the second input.

Pressed button for adding into an array.

**What I am trying to reach:**

```
var exampleArray = [[1, 1.5], [1, 1], [0, 25.5], [25, 1.5], [25.4, 1]];
```

**What I have reached:**

"Udefined" in the console log.

**Here Is jsfiddle link with my code:** https://jsfiddle.net/aectann/k3qwoz0g/12/

updated with snippet (ok, it was not hard at this time, MTCoster, thank you for advice):

```js
var totalInputs;
var myInputs;
var tmpARR = [];
var count = 0,
    types = ['t', 'C' /*, 'Q'*/ ],
    button = document.getElementById('button');

button.addEventListener("click", createInputs, false);

function createInputs() {
  if (!validInput()) {
    return;
  }
  count += 1;
  createInput(count);
}

function createInput(count) {
  totalInputs = document.getElementsByClassName('myInput').length;
  var existingNode = document.getElementsByClassName('myInput')[totalInputs - 1];

  types.forEach(function(type) {
    var newNode = existingNode.cloneNode();
    newNode.value = null;
    newNode.id = type + +count;
    newNode.placeholder = 'Placeholder ' + type;
    newNode.dataset.id = 'id' + count;
    appendNode(newNode);

  })
}

function appendNode(node) {
  document.querySelector('#div').appendChild(node);
}

function validInput() {
  myInputs = document.getElementsByClassName('myInput');
  var valid = true;

  Array.prototype.slice.call(myInputs).forEach(function(input) {

    input.classList.remove('error');
    if (!input.value) {
      input.classList.add('error');
      valid = false;
    }
  });

  return valid;
}

function removeError(event) {
  event.classList.remove('error');
}

function guardarNumeros() {
  boxvalue = document.getElementsByClassName('myInput').value;
  tmpARR.push(boxvalue);
  console.log(tmpARR);
  return false;
}
```

```css
#title {
  font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
  font-size: 200%;
}

#step {
  font-size: 15pt;
  clear: both;
}

#step2 {
  font-size: 15pt;
  clear: both;
}

#step3 {
  font-size: 15pt;
  clear: both;
}

summary {
  background: #009688;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
  text-align: left;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 250px;
  /*background-color: #4CAF50;*/
}

summary:hover {
  background: #008999;
}

.displayBlockInline-Flex {
  display: inline-flex;
}

#margin20 {
  margin-left: 20px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

#container {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: none;
}

a.myButton {
  color: #fff;
  /* цвет текста */
  text-decoration: none;
  /* убирать подчёркивание у ссылок */
  user-select: none;
  /* убирать выделение текста */
  background: rgb(212, 75, 56);
  /* фон кнопки */
  outline: none;
  /* убирать контур в Mozilla */
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 150px;
  padding-bottom: 11px;
}

a.myButton:hover {
  background: rgb(232, 95, 76);
}


/* при наведении курсора мышки */

a.myButton:active {
  background: rgb(152, 15, 0);
}


/* при нажатии */

.button1 {
  /*    background-color: #fc0; /* Цвет фона слоя */
  /*    padding: 5px; /* Поля вокруг текста */
  float: left;
  /* Обтекание по правому краю */
  width: 450px;
  /* Ширина слоя */
}

.button2 {
  /*    background-color: #c0c0c0; /* Цвет фона слоя */
  /*    padding: 5px; /* Поля вокруг текста */
  width: 650px;
  /* Ширина слоя */
  float: right;
  /* Обтекание по правому краю */
}

.clear {
  clear: left;
  /* Отмена обтекания */
}

.wrapper {
  width: 1100px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}


/*inputs*/

#div {
  text-align: center;
}

.myInput {
  height: 40px;
  outline: none;
  width: auto;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  margin: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.myInput.error {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

#action {
  margin: 10px 0;
  text-align: center;
}

#button {
  width: 190px;
  height: 40px;
  background: #009688;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 13px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: none;
  /*           text-transform: uppercase;*/
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#button:hover {
  background: #008999;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<center>
  <input type="text" class="myInput" name="nameAlloy" placeholder="Name">
</center>
<div id="div">
  <!--<form onsubmit="return guardarNumeros()">-->
  <div id="action">
    <button type="button" id="button">Add more inputs</button>
  </div>
  <input type="number" onkeypress="removeError(this)" class="myInput" data-id="id0" name="value[]" placeholder="Enter value 1">
  <input type="number" onkeypress="removeError(this)" class="myInput" data-id="id0" name="value[]" placeholder="Enter value 2">

  <div id="action">
    <input type="submit" id="button" value="Add to array">
  </div>
  <!--</form>-->
</div>
```

Comment: Please add the relevant code to the question as a runnable snippet (the `[<>]` button), rather than linking to jsfiddle.

Comment: I have tryied two times earlier, but I have failed and from those moment I am using jsfiddle. anyway it's more beautiful) but OK, I will try now

Comment: @PranshTiwari, yes, your variant works great. But now I have new issue: now I must push in `tmpARR` certain values in the certain positions. I should expalin this issue in this theme or create the new one?

Comment: Create a new one. I'll check it.

Comment: @PranshTiwari ok, have created https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53691934/push-values-from-inputs-in-certain-positions-in-an-array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The getElementsByClassName() method returns a collection of all
>   elements in the document with the specified class name, as a NodeList
>   object.

You can iterate over the collections for all the numeric inputs and update your result. But I would suggest is to create another class for numeric inputs, so you wouldn't need to check for the type of the input and would keep your code generic.

You can try this code and feel free to clear your doubts in the comments.

```
function guardarNumeros() {
    boxvalue = document.getElementsByClassName('myInput');
    i = 0;
    while (i < boxvalue.length) {
        if (boxvalue[i].type == "number") {
            if (boxvalue[i+1] && boxvalue[i+1].type == "number") {
                tmp = [boxvalue[i].value, boxvalue[i+1].value]
                tmpARR.push(tmp);
                i+=2;
            }
        } else {
            i++;
        }
    }
    console.log(tmpARR);
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is in "guardarNumeros" function because getElementsByClassName returns a collection and collection does not have a "value" property.

try this code

```
function guardarNumeros() {
    const inputs = [...document.getElementsByClassName('myInput')];
    const inputNumberArr = inputs.filter(x => x.type === 'number');
    // tmpARR = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < inputNumberArr.length; i++) {
      const element = inputNumberArr[i];
      if (i % 2 === 0) {
        tmpARR.push([element.value]);
      } else if (tmpARR[tmpARR.length -1] instanceof Array) {
        tmpARR[tmpARR.length -1].push(element.value);
      } else {
        tmpARR.push([element.value]);
      }
    }
      return false;
    }
```